# jquery dom manipulation without ID or CLASS

Tags: jquery, dom

i have HTML which looks something like this (the inputs have no ID or CLASS, some of them have other attributes such as VALUE)

```
<div id="yoo">
<div class="check">
     <input .......>
     <input .......>
     <input .......>
</div>

<div class="check">
      <input .......>
      <input .......>
      <input .......>
</div>
</div>
```

I need to be able to target a specific input from only one of the "check" divs using Jquery
I have tried the following

$("#sam .check input").remove() - this removes all the inputs.
$("#sam .check").eq(1).remove() - this removes the selected input from both "check"s
$("#sam .check").eq(1).("input").eq(2).remove() - I was hoping this would select a specific check element and within it select a specific input element, it does not work.

How do I select just one of the check elements and then select just one of the input elements within?

Is there any way to select a specific input element based on its index if there are a unknown number of other children (which are not inputs)?

Is there any way to select an element based on a attribute-value pair?

Comment: Yikes! two elements with the same ID is illegal.

Comment: Sorry thoes IDs were supposed to be CLASS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select a specific input you can use the `nth-child selector`

```
$('.check input:nth-child(2)').remove();
```

That will remove the second input of every element with the class `check`.

To remove from only one `check` div you could do the following:

```
$('.check:nth-child(1) input:nth-child(2)').remove();
```

That will remove the second input of the first element with the class `check`.

To select based on attribute-value pair just do this:

```
$('[attribute="value"]').remove();
```

Or if you like to point to a specific element with a specific argument:

```
$('input[value="whatever"]').remove();
```

Comment: could you also tell me how to select an element based on attribute-value pairs

once i have this ill give you a answered tick

Answer (score 0):

so you only want to select the checkboxes under the first div? you could always give them the same class name, IDs need to be unique. something like this:

change the divs to:

```
<div class="check">
    <input .......>
    <input .......>
    <input .......>
</div>
```

then this selector should remove the checkboxes.

```
$('.check:first input[type=checkbox]').remove();
```

not sure if that's exactly what you were going for, but hope it helps